# Distance between all the dots in a scatterplot in R

Tags: r, distance, scatterplot, euclidean

Is there any possibility in R to get a list of distances between all the points in a Scatterplot? For instance, this Scatterplot:[image]

So, I would like to obtain a list of distances among all the points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out the [dist](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/dist.html) function.

```
 x <- c(1,2,3,6,3,6)
 y <- c(4,5,7,8,9,0)
 dist(cbind(x,y))
```

produces the following output.

```
     1        2        3        4        5
2 1.414214                                    
3 3.605551 2.236068                           
4 6.403124 5.000000 3.162278                  
5 5.385165 4.123106 2.000000 3.162278         
6 6.403124 6.403124 7.615773 8.000000 9.486833
```

Comment: Perfect. And how could I reorder that matrix in two columns, the one on the left showing the two dots measured, and the one on the right the distances?

Comment: tmp <- dist(cbind(x,y))  now suppose $i > j$, the distance between point $i$ and point $j$ is stored in tmp[i-1][j].